# Where to store Qt imports for OSX deployment?

Tags: c++, qt, macos, deployment

I’m making my QT-application ready for shipping.
I’ve got one import -> QtDesktop.

I put it under Contents/imports (the dylib is under Contents/imports/QtDesktop/plugin).

Then I fixed its dependencies with install_name_tool -id & -change.

Upon starting the application it keeps saying “module “QtDesktop” is not installed”

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this excellent [link](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq09-mac-deployment.html) from Nokias Qt Documentation. They describe the steps you mention with `install_name_tool`. But they recommend putting plugins in a sligtly diffrent folder.

> Plugins can be put in the Contents/PlugIns section of a bundle. An
>   advantage of using this location is that the plugins will show up in
>   Finder and users can enable and disable them easily. For a Qt program
>   to take advantage of this feature, we must add this call to main():
>
> ```
> qApp->setLibraryPath(qApp->applicationDirPath() + "/../PlugIns");
> ```

Also check out the clever [macdeployqt](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2007/08/23/deploying-mac-applications-without-the-hassle/) script - It will do everything automatically for you. I've used it successfully on an application.